# Invalid < operator

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, operator-overloading, c++14

Hy! This is my first question on this site. Sorry for my English, if I will make mistakes:(

So, my problem is the following. I have simple class Date.

```
class Date
{
public:
    Date();
    Date(unsigned short day, unsigned short month, unsigned short year);
    Date(const Date &date);
    unsigned short getDay();
    unsigned short getMonth();
    unsigned short getYear();

    void setDay(unsigned short day);
    void setMonth(unsigned short month);
    void setYear(unsigned short year);

void printOnScreen()const;
friend
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Date& date) {
        out << date.day << "." << date.month << "." << date.year;
        return out;
    }

friend
    bool operator<(const Date& a, const Date& b) {
        if (a == b) {
            return false;
        }

        if (a.year < b.year) {
            return true;
        }
        if (a.month < b.month) {
            return true;
        }
        if (a.day < b.day) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
}

friend
    Date& operator-(Date& a) {
        return a;
    }

friend
    Date operator-(const Date& a, const Date& b) {
        return Date(
            abs(a.day - b.day),
            abs(a.month - b.month),
            abs(a.year - b.year)
            );
    }

friend
    bool operator==(const Date& date1, const Date& date2) {

        return (
            date1.day == date2.day &&
            date1.month == date2.month &&
            date1.year == date2.year
            );
    }

    virtual ~Date();
private:
    friend KeyHasher;

    unsigned short day;
    unsigned short month;
    unsigned short year;
};
```

In my main function I call sort like in this example, and after it get the error.

```
auto dates = {
    Date(1, 5, 2016),
    Date(3, 2, 2015),
    Date(3, 3, 2000),
    Date(2, 1, 1991),
    Date(1, 8, 2200),
    Date(1, 8, 2200),
    Date(1, 8, 2020),
    Date(21, 9, 2016)
};

vector<Date> v1(dates);
sort(
    v1.begin(),
    v1.end(),
    less<Date>()
);
```

What is wrong, I don't understand. Thank you for help.

Comment: If you have build errors, always include them in the body of the question. Please edit your question to include the full build output, as copy-pasted text, complete, in full and unedited.

Comment: Please get the text of the error messages from the Output Tab of Visual Studio and copy that to the question.

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/597ebd0069e798e3)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Your "less than" operator does not implement a strict weak order: for example, `Date(1, 1, 2016) < Date(2, 2, 2015)` will yield,`true`: the `year` is not smaller so the next case is taken and the `month` *is* smaller. You want to consider the `month` only when the `year` of the second argument is not less than the `year` of the first argument. I'm pretty sure this question has been asked [many] times before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator <` is indeed incorrect, use `std::tie`:

```
auto as_tuple(const Date& d) {
    return std::tie(d.year, d.month, d.day);
}

bool operator<(const Date& lhs, const Date& rhs) {
    return as_tuple(lhs) < as_tuple(rhs);
}

bool operator == (const Date& lhs, const Date& rhs) {
    return as_tuple(lhs) == as_tuple(rhs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your conditions like:

```
if (a.year < b.year)
    return true;
else if (a.year > b.year) 
    return false;
else // a.year == b.year
{
    if (a.month < b.month)
         return true;
    else if (a.month > b.month)
         return false;
    else // a.month == b.month
    {
        if (a.day < b.day)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When writing manually that code (instead of `std::tie`), I found more idiomatic to do `if (a.year != b.year) { return a.year < b.year; } if (a.month != b.month) { return a.month < b.month; } return a.day < b.day;`